# Mysterious error happening just in IE when displaying content in an iframe

Tags: java, internet-explorer, web-applications, iframe, wicket

I know that the following error will seem a bit obscure, but I think someone could have the key to circumvent it.

I am logging in into a website using httpunit, navigate to a certain page, again with httpunit and finally, from a link, I get the URL of the page I want to display inside an iframe in my own web application. (I have permission from the 3rd party to do this, that's not an issue).

I'm using wicket 6. I'm displaying the iframe in the following way:

```
RedirectPage page = new RedirectPage ( link );
InlineFrame frame = new InlineFrame ("myiframe", page );
```

I'm kind of new to wicket so this might not be the best way.

It works in every browser (Opera, Chrome, Firefox) except IE 10 (haven't tried for previous versions, just 10). In it the following error is showing in the iframe:

> Logi Debugger Trace Report
>   There was an error while processing your request.
>   The error was:
>   The Session variable "rdUserName" must be set when AuthenticationSource="AuthSession".

I know this error is displayed by the third party web application and may not necessarily match any known software error message but I'm looking for some possible solution / hack that could possibly make it work or at least a clue of what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer: it turns out that IE is stripping out the parameters from the URL for my iframe. It was that simple in the end.